# jPlayer initializing issue

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I want to make online radio using jPlayer, everithing is ok except one problem. The question is following.
As you know jPlayer used HTML5 and Flash if needed, so when I test it in Chrome it used HTML audio tag and everything is ok, but when I test it in other browsr (Opera, IE, FF) it used Flash and here is the problem, it initializing player two time, can anyone tell me why? Thanks for advance.

**UPDATE**
It's just a main package that we can download from jplayer.org. There is a part in the demo.html where is being initialization. When we try to write in this part alert('something'), we will see that this function is called 2 times.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            var data = $.ajax({
              url: "getsong.php",
              async: false
            }).responseText;
            alert(data)    // <-- alert will twice
            var string = data.split('|');
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: string[0]
            }).jPlayer("play");

            $('#artist').html(string[1]);
            $('#songname').html(string[2]);
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3"
    });
});
```

I think it's because of flash.

Comment: hi, it shouldn't initialise twice - i've never seen nor heard of this.. i don't even fully understand what you mean.. could you post your code, or link to a development page so we can diagnose?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried separating the methods you're using to get and use the data? Seems to me that you need the data before you need to play the jPlayer file. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = $.ajax({
        url: "getsong.php",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            alert(data)    // <-- alert will twice
            var string = data.split('|');
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: string[0]
            }).jPlayer("play");

            $('#artist').html(string[1]);
            $('#songname').html(string[2]);
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3"
    });
});
```